# dismessViewControllerAnimated is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, segue

I'm using a UIImagePickerController, and trying to take the image from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, and segue into another scene to display the image and edited image.

My didFinishingPickingWithMediaInfo method looks like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqual: @"public.image"]) {
        imageInfo = info;
        //Dismess pickerView
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
            NSLog(@"dismissed picker control successfully");
        }];
        //Perform segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imageSegue" sender:self];
}
```

and then I have it going to the prepareForSegue method as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual: @"imageSegue"]) {

        ImageViewController *ivc = [segue destinationViewController];
        ivc.imageInfo = self.imageInfo;
}
```

I tired adding a completion block at the end of the dismissViewControllerAnimated to log if it completed and it just jumps over that block never closes the pickerView, and therefor doesn't preform the segue.

Not sure why...any thought?

Comment: _Is_ `([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqual: @"public.image"])`?? And _is_ this the picker's delegate? I mean if it's not performing segue or dismissing the picker, it sounds to me like this code is not running at all. So first, prove to yourself that it is.

Comment: yes...declared in the .h file <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>.  I have set up a break point on all functions and it goes through them all, but just doesn't dismiss the picker view.

Comment: When I step over the code it goes it goes over the picker view, then steps into the perform segue, then into the prepareForSegue.  Since the pickerview never dismisses it doesn't move to the desired VC

Comment: Here's an idea: You are doing the `performSegue` before the dismissal has had any chance to complete. Try putting the `performSegue` _inside_ the completion handler of the dismissal so that it happens _after_ the dismissal.

Comment: Also instead of sending `dismiss` to the picker, try sending it to whoever actually presented it (probably `self`).

Comment: Perfect...Don't know why I didn't think about putting it in the completion block. That allowed it the time to close and then perform the segue

Comment: I'll formalize that as an actual answer with a bit more info.

Comment: You might want to read my book to get a better understanding of when animation runs: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_drawing_animation_and_threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing to understand. The order in which the lines of code appear here is not the order in which they are actually performed:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){
    NSLog(@"dismissed picker control successfully");
}];
//Perform segue
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imageSegue" sender:self];
```

`dismissViewController` *starts* the dismissal, but you have specified that you want animation, which is time-consuming (and does not even *start* until all your code has finished running). Meanwhile the code *goes right on*. So we reach `performSegue` immediately! Thus the dismissal never has a chance to complete. In fact, it has never even had a chance to start.

The way to guarantee order is to put the thing you want to have happen after the dismissal (i.e. `performSegue`) *in the completion block* of the dismissal. That, not to put too fine a point on it, is exactly what the completion block is *for*; it is code that is guaranteed *not* to run until the dismissal *has completed*.